# Application of a Laplace transform property to solve a definite (improper) integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I want to solve the following integral using Laplace transform properties:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt $$

The result is $\frac\pi2\ $. There is a Laplace transform property concerning integrals:

$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\int_0^x f(t) dt\right)=\frac{\mathcal{L}(f)(s)}{s}  $$

I saw a procedure from a colleague which has a step that goes like this:

$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt\right)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+s^2} ds  $$

The above expression seems like if the transform could be introduced inside the integral and applied to the integrand, with integration limits unaffected by this operation. I would like to know whether this step is correct and, if it isn't, what is the correct application of the aforementioned property to solve the integral? Also, does the final value theorem hold in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{sint}{t}dt , (s=0)$

or $I=\mathcal{L}[\frac{sint}{t}]=\int_s^\infty \frac{1}{s^2+1}ds=\frac{\pi}{2}-tan^{-1}s=\frac{\pi}{2} $ at $s=0$.

The property is $\mathcal{L}[f(t)/t]=\int_s^\infty F(s)ds$ where $\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=F(s)$.

Comment: @Aryadeva...hawk-eye observation! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I now fully understand how to apply the Laplace transform to solve integrals of functions with nonelementary primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following integral:
$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t} e^{-st}dt$$
$$I(s)=\mathcal{L}\left (\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right )$$
$$I(s)=\int_s^\infty \frac{du}{u^2+1} $$
$$I(s)=\bigg|\arctan u \bigg|_s^\infty  $$
$$I(s)=\dfrac {\pi}2-\arctan s $$
You can evalute your intergal now:
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt=I(0)=\dfrac {\pi}2$$

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I now fully understand how to apply the Laplace transform to solve integrals of functions with nonelementary primitives.

Comment: @inghans you're welcomed. It's easy to integrate these definite integrals with Laplace Transform.